# Subst drive letter fails to create DB in EF framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-5

I am using VS2013 and EF5 to build some sample applications. The development code is available in one of my directories, and as a habit I susbt that code directory to a drive.

If I open the solution, a subdirectory, under the subst drive letter; the DB Context (DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges) fails to create the DB.

After a lot of looking around and checking permissions (ensuring I had 'Full Control' on the directory), I re-opened the solution from the original directory path. This time it worked.

Anyone facing similar issues with subst drives? Any alternate or workarounds??

Thanks in advance

Prakash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subst drive will be for the current user, but the database engine may be running as a service which logs on using different credentials. If so, the subst drive will not be available to the service.

In this case, a possible fix is to change the service's logon credentials to the same as the user who has subst the drive (although this isn't always possible or even sensible).

Otherwise, you will have to use UNC or the full unsubsted path.

Comment: or maybe use one or more `xp_cmdshell` to subst.